# Draw Image With Transform In Draw In Rect

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics

I would Like to save `UIImage` with rotation in `drawInRect`.
I am having four `UImageView` objects from which **second** and *third* has Rotation of **100 degree** and *250 degree* respectively.
So can anyone tell me how can I give rotation to those images which are inside `UIImageView`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you to solve your problem,

for 100 degree rotation  if you want to keep for 250 degree please replace 100 with 250 degrees.

for 100 degrees

```
(UIImageview *).transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.744);
```

for 250 degress

```
(UIImageview *).transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(4.36);
```

This code is as per your requirement

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
//I want Rotation for second and third Image//
 [secondImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 300)]; 
 secondImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.744);

[thirdImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 300)]; 
thirdImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(4.36);
[fourthImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,fourthImage.size.width ,fourthImage.size.height )]; 

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Comment: this is my code..

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );     
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
         

//I want Rotation for second and third Image//
             
[secondImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 300)];

[thirdImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 300)];
     
//..... //           
     
[fourthImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,fourthImage.size.width ,fourthImage.size.height )];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

Comment: I guess UIImage don't have transform property.. please check again

Comment: Please make it as UIimageview and keep image to the imageview and assign tranform functionality